# Toggle between functions - only execute either one on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle between two jQuery functions. It has to be done on page load - and each page load should only execute one of the scripts.

This is what I got so far:

HTML:

```
<button class=".click">Click me</button>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("addClass") > -1) {
        $("body").addClass("test");
    }
    else {
        $("body").addClass("secondtest");
    }
    $('.click').on('click', function() {
        console.log("Clicked");
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) {
            url += '?param=addClass'
        } else {
            url += '?param=1'
        }
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

This Gets me a bit on the way, the first click adds `?param=1` on the first click - nothing happens - second click it adds the `?param=addClass` and the body gets the class. If I click again it adds `?param=addClass` every time.

I want one of the script to run as default - then I want the first button click to reload and run the other script instead. If I click once more I want it to reverse the url so the first script loads, like a toggle.

I now there is an easy way to just toggle classes, but I specifically need to run one of two scripts on a new page load.

Update:

```
$(function() {
if (window.location.href.indexOf("addClass") > -1) {
$("body").addClass("test");
}
else {
$("body").addClass("secondtest");
}
$('.click').on('click', function() {
console.log("Clicked");
var url = window.location.pathname;
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.indexOf('?param=1') > -1) {
url = url.replace("param=1", "")+'param=addClass'
} else {
url = url.replace("?param=addClass", "")+'?param=1'
}
window.location.href = url;
});
});
```

This set the body class on first page load - then first click ads ?param=1 but doesnt change the body class. Second click replaces ?param=1 with ?param=addClass and changes the body class - after that the toggles works. So How do I make it work from the first click?

Comment: What do you want to load as a default here?

Comment: Doesnt really mather - If can control the outcome from any of them. If I just could get one set as default of those two then the rest gets solved.

Comment: You just want to toggle the urls or the classes as well?

Comment: One of your problems may be that you are constantly adding `?` to the url. There can only be one set of query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This will be the default functionality, if no query string is present then add `?param=1`:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.indexOf('?param=1')==-1 )
  {
    window.location.href = url+"?param=1";
  }
```

This will be the `onclick` functionality to toggle the `urls` as it is replacing the existing functionality.

```
$('.click').on('click', function() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (url.indexOf('?param=1') > -1) {
            url = url.replace("param=1", "")+'param=addClass'
        } else {
            url = url.replace("?param=addClass", "")+'?param=1'
        }
        window.location.href = url;
});
```

If you want to toggle the classes as well you can use `.toggleClass("test secondtest")`

Comment: @viod se mu update - it almost works now - the only problem is that it needs two clicks to start the toggle.

Comment: First click for param=addClass and second click to add param=1. what is the issue @user3344734

Comment: it first gets secondclass as defualt on pagelaod - the click ads param=1 which doesn't do any change to the body class (which i want on the first click) then second click replaces it with param=addClass which changes the body class (as i want) then third revert the url to param=1  and the body class with it. So I need to click twice for the toggle to start

Comment: To clarify - the first pageload doesn't add anything to the url - its also not the base url im outputting this script so there is already a string to the url. Not sure if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is in this `if`:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) {
    url += '?param=addClass'
} else {
    url += '?param=1'
}
```

#### Scenario 1: `/test.html`

`indexOf('?')` will be negative. You will then redirect the user to `/test.html?param=1`

#### Scenario 2: `/test.html?param=1`

`indexOf('?')` will then be positive. You will then redirect the user to `/test.html?param=1?param=addClass`

#### Scenario 3: `/test.html?param=addClass`

`indexOf('?')` will then be positive. You will then redirect the user to `/test.html?param=addClass?param=addClass`

So... what is wrong?

You are using `window.location.href`. Excellent for setting the path but bad if you want to actually manage the query parameters.

#### Solution

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var hasParams = window.location.href.indexOf('?') > -1;
if (hasParams) {
    url += '?param=addClass'
} else {
    url += '?param=1'
}
window.location.href = url;
```

Since you are redirecting on the same host (seen with your code), you only need the `pathname`. `pathname` doesn't include parameters (`?key=value&...`) and can be used to redirect a user on the same domain.

Comment: Hi! thats looks better with the urls - however it not working quite as I want yet- The site loads with one of the script executed and gives the the body the class .secondtest - so far so good. First click ads ?param=1 - no change in the body class - second click replaces the ?param=1 with ?param=addClass and it also changes the body class. Third click does nothing, it keeps the ?param=addClass

Comment: Well we can't do all the work for you either. At that point, you are literally 1 step away from success. You have the url... you have parameters... you could even check for `window.location.search`.

Comment: Hi! Update the question, im almost there now. Thanks for the help! And yeah I kjow its close - but i've been around it for a while now so Im more at the confuzed state right now!